# Implement a function to return top rated movies in the network of movie

Tags: c#, binary-tree

Given class below:

```
public class Movie
{
    private readonly char movieId;
    private readonly float rating;
    private List<Movie> similarMovies; // Similarity is bidirectional

    public Movie(char movieId, float rating)
    {
        this.movieId = movieId;
        this.rating = rating;
        similarMovies = new List<Movie>();
    }

    public char getId()
    {
        return movieId;
    }

    public float getRating()
    {
        return rating;
    }

    public void addSimilarMovie(Movie movie)
    {
        similarMovies.Add(movie);
        movie.similarMovies.Add(this);
    }

    public List<Movie> getSimilarMovies()
    {
        return similarMovies;
    }     

    public static IList<Movie> getMovieRecommendations(Movie movie, int numTopRatedSimilarMovies)
    {
        //Implement this method         
        return null;
    }
}
```

```
reachable from the current movie
         eg:            A(Rating 1.2)
                        /   \
                     B(2.4)  C(3.6)
                       \     /
                        D(4.8)
```

In the above example edges represent similarity and the number is rating.
          getMovieRecommendations(A,2)should return C and D (sorting order doesn't matter so it can also return D and C)
          getMovieRecommendations(A,4) should return A, B, C, D (it can also return these in any order eg: B,C,D,A)
          getMovieRecommendations(A,1) should return D. Note distance from A to D doesn't matter

Answer (score 0):

```
 public static HashSet<Movie> sd = new HashSet<Movie>();
    public static IList<Movie> getMovieRecommendations(Movie movie, int numTopRatedSimilarMovies)
    {
        sd.Add(movie);
        foreach (Movie m in movie.getSimilarMovies())
        {
            if (!sd.Contains(m))
                getMovieRecommendations(m, -1);
        }
        if(numTopRatedSimilarMovies > -1)
            return sd.OrderByDescending(o => o.rating).Take(numTopRatedSimilarMovies).ToList();            
        return null;
    }
```